# Error when I connect hive through pyhive: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: anaconda, pyhive

The error occurred like this:

[image]

I use pyhive in vitual env of anaconda3. I can connect hive successfully several days ago. It crashed suddenly today without any changes. I tried to update the conda and pyhive to the latest version, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try with another Hive connector such as `impyla`?

Comment: Out of curiosity: did you try with Python 3?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter You're right! I update python2 to python3 in conda, and install pyhive again. Now it works. Thanks!